# Environment Variable.js file cant be show in Browser

Tags: javascript, frontend

Backend application URL mentioned at .env file at Root Directory, but When I access front end application (React) in inspect mode I am able to see that Environment Variable.js file and content of the file. I want to hide that file when client inspect the browser it wont show.

[image]

I tried dotenv but I can't use dotenv in my application as per client request.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in the root with no name and just the extension being ".env".

For more documentation and how to use dotenv environment variables read the dotenv [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the response, But My client don't said that don't want to use dotenv.

Comment: Okay... That's an unusual request. You could try encrypting the data with bcrypt. This wont remove it from the inspector but would protect it. Usually dotenv is used because it is already used by React and globally available in your application while being really secure.

Comment: a small question if it is silly i am sorry. dotenv will use in react build only? here i am building react app then, deploying on Ngnix container. as per my knowledge dotenv will use in npm start.  i am right ? or else can you share your knowledge. 
Thank you.

Comment: If you use the values from the dotenv file in your application then it will be required both for the build and for development.

Comment: actually I am using environment _varible.js file. not using dotenv. in dockerfile used RUN npm ci, COPY . . , RUN npm run build.  in this case client unable to see environment_varible.js file in chrome in N/w tab like above picture. How can i achieve this. Thank you